# Not able to access my .css.php using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i am trying to access this link on my site 
http://mydomain.com/lib/utils/utils.js.php
http://mydomain.com/resources/script/myapp.home.js.php

my .htaccess file is like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^resources/(.*).(css\.php|js\.php) ../build/resources/$1.$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^lib/(.*).(css\.php|js\.php) ../build/lib/$1.$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^lib/(.*).(css|js|txt|jpeg|jpg|png|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff) ../lib/$1.$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^resources/(.*).(css|js|txt|jpeg|jpg|png|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff) ../resources/$1.$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

my folder structure is

```
app/handler/x.php
lib/utils/utils.js
build/resources/script/myapp.home.js.php
build/lib/utils/utils.js.php
resources/script/myapp.home.js
web/index.php
web/.htacsess
```

mydomain.com points to web folder

but i am able to access this link:-http://mydomain.com/index.php
but all other files via .htacess ,all I get is 400 bad Request

Answer (score 0):

If you're on apache, try to edit the file "default" in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and set

```
AllowOverride All
```

in place off

```
AllowOverride None
```

than restart apache (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart)